# Elevation from GPS Vs. Query Elevation from Static TOPO database like SRTM

Tags: gps, elevation, topography, srtm, terrain

As far as I understand the GPS determines Elevation by real time calculations. What I don't understand is how?

For example let's assume perfect (errors free) Lat/Lon fix by GPS. So I can query static (Raster) TOPO data base like SRTM 1 arc second, and get elevation relevant for 1 arc second resolution. If the GPS fix has error so I get location to the next 1 arc second rectangle - In addition to the 1 arc second resolution error, I have error in getting location for the incorrect 1 arc second rectangle.

But how the GPS calculates the elevation (assuming not in the mentioned way), and does the vertical accuracy generally considered so severe, so the query DB eventually can be better?

Comment: GPS error is likely to be *way* larger than 1 arc-second -- you're looking at 16-25 DTED tiles

Comment: @Vince Does the GPS calculates elevation based on some static DB or in other method?

Comment: 3-D trig only. Please do some [basic research](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/travel/gps.htm) before posting.